# java subcadenas

Tags: java, string, substring

hola quiero crear un función que dado dos cadenas: cadena1 = "hola", cadena2= "**ola**".
me diga si cadena2 esta dentro de cadena1 y si esto se cumple quiero que la función devuelva un nuevo string reemplazando cadena2 por su **inverso** , de este modo nuevaCadena = "h**alo**". En fin si alguien podría ayudarme o orientarme en como hacerlo porfa muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola. Las publicaciones que presentan un problema para que otros lo resuelvan, sin tener ningun intento  no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Por favor, revisa [como hacer un pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tienes un ejemplo de lo quieres hacer:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String cadena1 = "hola";
      String cadena2= "ola";
      
      String resultado = null;
      
      // Si cadena1 contiene cadena2 entonces:
      if (cadena1.contains(cadena2)) {
          // resultado es igual a cadena1 reemplazando el texto de cadena 2 por el resultado de new StringBuilder(cadena2).reverse().toString()
          resultado = cadena1.replace(cadena2, new StringBuilder(cadena2).reverse().toString());
      }else {
          // si cadena1 no contiene cadena2:
          resultado = cadena1;
      }

      // imprimir resultado
      System.out.println(resultado);
    }
```

Output:

```
halo
```